# Chrome extension taken down under "single purpose Chrome extensions policy"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have made a chrome extension with the name Newsprompt : Personal Breaking News(gcajgpbafhkbkdpbaaipjoiajnangjhp) is recently being taken down stating that it breaks "single purpose Chrome extensions policy". It shows the breaking news in new tab and keep learning about user preference to push the articles(not news) user is interested in. No adds, no hidden functionality. That is all the extension does. Since it has been taken down, I have constantly been following up with 
chromewebstore-dev-support@google.com and removed a lot of features (personalization being one of them) but all they come back with exactly same copy pasted lines from the docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose that it doesn't comply with their standards. It feels like talking to a bot whose only response is "it doesn't comply with standards". So my question being:
1. Has any developers faced the same issue? (I have seen a couple of developers complaining on google groups but no one getting a solution). If yes how did they **solved/escalated the problem** (It felt like wasting 6 months of my team's effort for nothing).
2. I have tried https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support but no response.
3. Any further leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Getting an extension reviewed at chrome store is PITA. Hit and trial worked for me. It was highly random.